# Erro 404 em URLs amigaveis no Wordpress Revenda Locaweb Plesk

Tags: wordpress, plesk

Utilizo A Revenda de Sites da Locaweb em Plesk, e estou subindo um site feito no Wordpress.
Os links permanentes não funcionam.

O site só funciona nas configurações padrão de Links  `www.endereco.com.br/?p=123`. Se eu coloco os links com o *nome do post*, por exemplo: `http://www.endereco.com.br/post-exemplo/`, ele dá a mensagem de erro 404.

Ele indica que a página requerida é a seguinte:

```
Requested URL   http://www.endereco.com.br:80/como-funciona/
```

Alguém consegue me dar uma luz?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Algumas coisas tem que ser verificadas, entre elas o WP precisa de um arquivo .htaccess com as configurações para a reescrita (os comandos que o servidor web irá utilizar para resolver a URL, o seu permalink por exemplo irá passar a slug 'como-funciona' para o arquivo index.php, que irá localizar o tipo de página e decidir o que será apresentado, o erro 404 indica que isto não está ocorrendo), normalmente o WP gera e exibe na página de permalinks.

Outra coisa que é necessário ter é o mod_rewrite do apache habilitado, por ser locaweb acredito que deve estar habilitado.

Aqui tem a página do WP que explica como fazer -> http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks#Where.27s_my_.htaccess_file.3F

Espero que isso lhe ajude.